# Verify getChildElement() is not null

Tags: apex, webservices, xml, httpresponse

As a follow up to my previous post: [REST API calls to 3rd Party (Pardot), multiple @future callouts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53766/rest-api-calls-to-3rd-party-pardot-multiple-future-callouts/53780#53780)

There are two responses I expect back when I attempt this Web Service callout to Pardot:

**1) Success**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok" version="1.0">
    <api_key>6d800bfaab63274b1b908dacd8544936</api_key>
</rsp>`

**2) Failure**:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="fail" version="1.0">
    <err code="15">Login failed</err>
</rsp>`

The problem is if I attempt to parse the success and it was a failed attempt then I get a debug status error of "Attempt to de-reference a null object" So I'm wondering if there is a way to do a try() or if() statement that will look for fail or success and then return the other, something like this in theory:

```
/* Try to send the request */
try {
    response = http.send(request);
    System.debug('::RESPONSE::'+response.getBody());

    /* Setup Document for parsing */
    Dom.Document doc = response.getBodyDocument();
    Dom.XMLNode results = doc.getRootElement();

//=======================================
  NOTE: Currently if this next line fails
        then everything stops so the if 
        statement never happens.
===========================================//

    String api_key = results.getChildElement('api_key', null).getText();
    if( api_key != '' ){
        return api_key;
    } else {
        System.debug('::API REQUEST ERROR:: '+results.getChildElement('err', null).getText());
        return '';
    }
} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    System.debug('ERROR: '+ e);
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous answer I gave you assumed success, but for robustness, you can certainly iterate through all expected values. For example:

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(res.getBody());
Dom.XmlNode root = doc.getRootElement();
if(root.getName()=='rsp') {
    for(Dom.XmlNode node1: root.getChildElements()) {
        if(node1.getName()=='err') {
            // handle error condition
        }
        if(node1.getName()=='api_key') {
           // store api_key for use
        }
    }
}
```

If you reach the end without an API key or error, that just means that you ran out of nodes, and should probably just throw some general exception, instead.

See the [XmlNode Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode) documentation for more assistance on using this built-in library.

Comment: For completeness can you update your code to include the try() response and the exception you're referring to. Thanks trying this out now

Comment: @Xtremefaith This code won't crash by itself-- the idea would be that you may want to report the error to the calling function, so the try-catch would be higher up the call stack. For example, getChildElements() returns an empty array if there are no elements, and an empty loop never executes its body.

Comment: very strange when compiling for deploy I get this: **Error:  Invalid type: XmlNode** @ `XmlNode root = doc.getRootElement();`  and the response shows the body as expected so not sure the problem

Comment: I forgot XmlNode is in the Doc namespace. See modified answer.

Comment: Awesome that worked great. To store the API_Key now would I just use this: `String api_key = root.getChildElement('api_key', null).getText();` ?

Comment: By the way, may want to review again, your first for() is the child nodes so there is no `rsp` as you're already in that, instead you just need 1 for() loop for this example